# euler fraktur variations

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, amsfonts, variant

The `eufm` font family from AMS has certain lowercase variations, namely d, f, g, k, t, u, as shown in the second row of the table attached below. My question is: Using (La)TeX, how can one make (part of) them as default? I was looking at some option or some encoding information, but I was not able to find anything so far.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your aim is just to access those glyphs, it can be done as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from amsfonts.sty
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
%\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerfraktur}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{eulerfraktur}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathfrak}{eulerfraktur}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakd}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varvarfrakd}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakf}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varvarfrakf}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakg}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakk}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakt}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfraku}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"07}

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{d}\ne\varfrakd\ne\varvarfrakd$

$\mathfrak{f}\ne\varfrakf\ne\varvarfrakf$

$\mathfrak{g}+\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{t}+\mathfrak{u}$

$\varfrakg+\varfrakk+\varfrakt+\varfraku$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to replace, say `\mathfrak{f}` with `\varfrakf`, it's a bit more complicated. I'll add replacements for all `\var` (not `\varvar`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from amsfonts.sty
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
%\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerfraktur}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{eulerfraktur}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\usemathfrak}{eulerfraktur}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakd}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varvarfrakd}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakf}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varvarfrakf}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakg}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakk}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfrakt}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varfraku}{\mathord}{eulerfraktur}{"07}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mathfrak}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([dfgktu]) } { \c{varfrak\1} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \usemathfrak{\l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{dfgktu}$

$\usemathfrak{dfgktu}$ % for comparison

\end{document}
```

You still have the original available with `\usemathfrak`.

[image]

If you want to use `\varvarfrakf` instead, just remove the definition of `\varfrakf` and one `var` in the following one.